# onclick the second time round click

Tags: javascript, onclick

not sure if this is possible keeping the code simple, but im trying to make it so that i have an image, when you clicked it, it goes to a new image. then when you click that image, it goes back to the original image.
my code is:

```
function save_data()
{
if ( document.images.save.src == "saved.png") document.images.save.src="save.png";
if (document.images.save.src == "save.png") document.images.save.src="saved.png";
}


<img id="save"  onclick="save_data()" src="save.png">
```

Comment: what's the problem with what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be simplified.

Using

```
<img id="save"  onclick="save_data(this)" src="save.png">`
```

You can do

```
function save_data(img)
{
  img.src = /saved/i.test(img.src) ? 'save.png' : 'saved.png';
}
```

If this doesn't work, it may have to do with the fact that `saved.png` is not in the path the html is in. So try it with a full URL:

```
function save_data(img)
{
  var imgpath = 'http://yoursite.com/imgpath/';
  img.src = imgpath + (/saved/i.test(img.src) ? 'save.png' : 'saved.png');
}
```

A note: it may be better to assign the click handler [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (see also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice))

Comment: Yes, this is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`if ( document.images.save.src == "saved.png")` - this won't work, because `.src` returns the full path to the image, not just the filename. For example, `http://site.com/path/images/saved.png`.

Try matching substrings instead.

```
function save_data()
{
if ( document.images.save.src.indexOf("saved.png") != -1) document.images.save.src="save.png";
if (document.images.save.src.indexOf("save.png") != -1) document.images.save.src="saved.png";
}
```